# migrating lexer action from v3 to v4

Tags: antlr3, antlr4

I have a grammar that works with v3, and I am now trying to migrate to v4. I have taken some hints from questions [18431158](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778570/) and [14778570](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431158/), but I have one more question:

In my v3 code, I was counting line numbers like this (newLine() just keeps a count of lines parsed and saves it, so that later, when I try to report some semantic errors, I could also report the corresponding line number):

```
COMMENT : '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : 
    (
       '\n' {newLine();}
     | ~ '\n'
    ) )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
;
LINE_COMMENT : '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN; newLine();} ;
WS: (
  ' '
 |'\r'
 |'\t'
 |'\n' {newLine();}
)+     {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

In v4, the lexer actions are not permitted inside. How do I migrate this code to v4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR 4 always tracks the line and column numbers in the [`Token`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html) objects. You can simply remove the actions which call the `newLine()` method and use [`Token.getLine()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html#getLine%28%29).

Comment: Thanks. Your reply for question 19350705 was also helpful.